# Polymorphism , Can I choose the correct class using method parameters?

Tags: java, polymorphism

I have a method

```
someMethod(List<SomeType> v);
```

and I want if 
   SomeType is of type SubType1, then call

```
new SubType1().someMethod(List<SubType1> v)
```

And if 
SomeType is of type SubType2, then call

```
new SubType2().someMethod(List<SubType2> v)
```

is there any way to do this without using instanceof ?

***Update***
even instanceof can't be used due to type erasure .... I have no idea how to do it

Comment: This is literally the basis of polymorphism. I highly suggest reading books/websites on polymorphism and inheritance (they kind of go hand in hand)

Comment: How do you do that with `instanceof`? edit: Can you give an example with a little more context in code how you imagine all this? This is currently a little [XY-Problem-ish](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @JackWilliams but it won't guarantee type checking

Comment: @JackWilliams ... sorry there was  a typo ....the polymorphism is in the method arg (SomeType)

Comment: The short answer is: no, you can't. That's related to specialization, and Java doesn't support it. Half-related: http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/valhalla/specialization.html

Comment: The question makes no sense to me at all. Are all the `someMethod`s the same method? What is supposed to happen if you do `subType1Instance.someMethod(list)` where list is a `List<SubType2>`?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like below and then each implementation could be suit to their subtype,

```
Public Class Type() {

    public void someMethod(List v) {

    }
}

public Class SubType1 extends Type {

    @override
    public void someMethod(List v) {
        //SubType 1 specific implementation
    }
}

public Class SubType2 extends Type {

    @override
    public void someMethod(List v) {
        //SubType 2 specific implementation
    }
}
```

Comment: plz check the quest again, the polymorphism is in the method arg

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing something like

```
class BaseType<T extends BaseType> {

    public void someMethod(List<T> param) {
        //your logic
    }
}
```

and then extends it:

```
class SomeType1 extends BaseType<SomeType1> {
    @Override
    public void someMethod(List<SType1> param) {
       // specific behavior here
    }
}
```

and respectively

```
class SomeType1 extends BaseType<SomeType1> {

}
```

**UPDATED**

added `@Override` example

Comment: plz check the quest again, the polymorphism is in the method arg

Comment: So I can't think of any other solution to your problem other than I suggested. You want your type to be type parameter so try this.